# OMNET++ 5.1 opp_makemake

Tags: omnet++

I installed OMNET++ 5.1 on my Ubuntu 16 OS and imported my project into the Eclipse IDE. But I can not compile my project as before. Make is giving me error:

> make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdDLY.png): *** No rule to make target 'msgheaders'.  Stop.

I have a folder called loggingWindow that has its own custom makefile and is excluded from the source.

[image]

But I noticed that the generated makefile is not correct:

[image]

The makefile is calling msgheaders and smheaders targets in the logginWindow folder. The loggingWindow is a completely separate application with its own makefile and has no idea about mshheader!

Also `make clean` does not work!
The clean window stuck without any progress:

[image]

As a temporary workaround, I have added phony targets (msgheaders, smheaders) in order to compile my project.

Comment: You can always delete the Makefile, regenerate it or create a new OMNeT project and import your source code manually afterwards to fix Makefile issues.

Comment: @MichaelKirsche: The Makefile is not generated by the opp_makemake. That's the Makefile that I wrote myself and asked omnet to run it for me. That's why I excluded that folder from source. I guess my issue is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can add these targets to your own `Makefile` in `logginWindow`, for example:

```
msgheaders:
    echo Do nothing

smheaders:
    make all

# content from your existing Makefile
all: 
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing in order to compile my project as before. Thanks for mentioning that as an answer. I updated my post.